# sendmail_from for setting a proper name and email ignored by mail() in PHP when set by .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, sendmail

When setting the `sendmail_from` variable via `.htaccess`, what is the proper syntax to set both the name and the address?

I tried 
`php_value sendmail_from "ProperName <noreply2@example.com>"`

but it did not use that value in outgoing mail. `phpinfo()` does show the local value as the same as what I placed in the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Windows? I ask because the option is only available for windows: http://php.net/sendmail_from

Comment: Have you set `AllowOverride Options`?